Mocking function in the class that i want to test
I am trying to write unit test for my project using moq package.
[Fact]
public async Task Login_WrongPasswordTryLimitNotReached_ReturnWrongPasswordAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var service = new Mock<AuthService>(_userManager.Object, _roleManager.Object, _configuration.Object, _roleService.Object, _dbContext.Object) { CallBase = true };

    User user = new User { FirstName = "admin", LastName = "admin", Status = UserStatus.Active };
    _userManager.Setup(x => x.CheckPasswordAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(false);
    _userManager.Setup(x => x.FindByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(user);
    service.Setup(x => x.IsLoginFailLimitReached(user)).ReturnsAsync(false);

    AuthenticateDto authenticateDto = new AuthenticateDto();

    // Act
    var result = await service.Object.Login("admin", "password");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal((authenticateDto, "Hatalı şifre"), result);

}

I cannot mock IsLoginFailLimitReached since it is not virtual and also it was a private that is only meaningful in the AuthService class. I changed IsLoginFailLimitReached to be public and virtual. But is there a better solution without changing the implementation?

If you want to replace a dependency with a Test Double (Moq, hand-rolled, or any other library) the members you want to control must be overridable in some way. If you want to use Moq, these are the constraints that the code must obey.
Alternatively, you may consider whether you could make IsLoginFailLimitReached a pure function (if it isn't already). If it's a pure function, you don't need to replace it with a Test Double to control its behaviour, since you can already control it by feeding it appropriate input.
